# How to get access all selected elements data value in JosephSKh's DropdownTree

Tags: jquery, html, treeview, dropdownbox

I want to access all data value of [JosephSKh's DropdownTree](https://github.com/JosephSKh/DropdownTree) like this

```
var arr4=[
            {title:"St Fatima",href:"#1",dataAttrs:[{title:"id",data:"value1"}]}
            ,
            {title:"Korba",href:"#2",dataAttrs:[{title:"id",data:"value4"}]}
            ,
            {title:"Roxi",href:"#3",dataAttrs:[{title:"id",data:"value7"}]}
        ];
```

From the above code, I want to access value1, value4, value7 if all are selected

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to loop through the array of Objects `arr4` and fetch the deep nested property `data`. In order to do that, I recommend the following Javascript line:

ES5 syntax:

`arr4.forEach(function(item) { console.log(item.dataAttrs[0].data); } );`

ES6 syntax:

`arr4.forEach(item => console.log(item.dataAttrs[0].data));`

Now, you should replace the `console.log` with the action you want. For example if you had an array to collect those values, you could edit the above line as:

ES5 syntax:

`arr4.forEach(function(item) { babluArray.push(item.dataAttrs[0].data); } );`

ES6 syntax:

`arr4.forEach(item => babluArray.push(item.dataAttrs[0].data));`

Read further: [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), [Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)